# Return lowest level directory of multiple directories

Tags: powershell

I have a folder with a large list of directories. I wish return the path of each folder that have no more directories within as a string

Example Directory structure

```
C:\Users\Test\Desktop\xml\xml\User1\User1\user1\Windows\abc
C:\Users\Test\Desktop\xml\xml\User1\User1\user1\Windows1\
C:\Users\Test\Desktop\xml\xml\User2\User2\user2\Windows\
C:\Users\Test\Desktop\xml\xml\User2\User2\user2\Windows1\abc
```

Preferred output

```
C:\Users\Test\Desktop\xml\xml\User1\User1\user1\Windows\abc
C:\Users\Test\Desktop\xml\xml\User2\User2\user2\Windows1\abc
```

I have done the below, but this return each folder alow the way, through the directory structure not just the lowest level one.

```
foreach ($i in Get-ChildItem $Path -Directory -Recurse | Select FullName){
Write-Host $i.FullName
}
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking, select the path with the greatest depth per User1/2? Your code doesn't show any effort to distinguish the pathes by whatever criteria.

Comment: You need to distinguish the path and a simple if statement will allow you to determine the "lowest" directory based on the length of the path.

Comment: Try this: [Finding the bottom folders of a file tree using PowerShell](https://stuart-moore.com/finding-bottom-folders-file-tree-using-powershell/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
function GetLowestLevelRecursive([System.Collections.IList] $directories)
{
    $lowestleveldirs = @()
    foreach ($dir in $directories)
    {
        $childDirs = $dir.GetDirectories();
        if ($childDirs.Length -gt 0)
        {
            $lowestleveldirs += GetLowestLevelRecursive $childDirs
        }
        else
        {
            $lowestleveldirs += $dir
        }
    }
    return $lowestleveldirs
}

#input directories
$allDirectories = @()

# search for lowest level directories
$lowestlvldirs = GetLowestLevelRecursive $allDirectories

foreach ($dir in $lowestlvldirs)
{
    Write-Host $dir.FullName
}
```

Expected output:

```
C:\Users\Test\Desktop\xml\xml\User1\User1\user1\Windows\abc
C:\Users\Test\Desktop\xml\xml\User2\User2\user2\Windows1\abc
```